# What is gid in the aria2 download report?

Tags: aria2

I'm trying to make sense of aria2. There is a column in aria2 download report called gid which is made of 6 alphanumeric characters. What is the purpose of this column? Is it some kind of identity?? and How we can query aria2 internal db programmatically?

```
Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
72b40a|OK  |   300KiB/s|/path/to/downlaod/direcotry
f35190|OK  |   200KiB/s|/path/to/download/directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, GID is an ID of a download which `aria2c` uses to identify a particular download.

> The GID must be hex string of 16 characters, thus [0-9a-zA-Z] are allowed and leading zeros must not be stripped. The GID must be unique, otherwise error is reported and the download is not added.

Usually the GID is generated by aria2. You can manually set GID by using [`--gid`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-gid) option.